# Android Debug and Turning on DDMS

Tags: android, ddms

Right now, I don't have the DDMS to output anything on the Logcat. Everything is just on the console.

Is DDMS launched automatically without using the Log.d Log.e statements on the code?
I don't have such Log statements in my code. Now if I want to use DDMS and log statement needed where I should put those log statements and what's content of those statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDMS is never launched "automatically". And no special Log statements are required. Logs are continually written to a circular buffer on the device and DDMS will display the logs from connected devices (among other things) if/when you start it up.

If you want to use DDMS from the android eclipse plugins, just starting up eclipse (with ADT installed) will start pulling in logs in the DDMS perspective. Simply switch perspective in eclipse to view the logs.

If you want to start up DDMS without the android eclipse plugins, then you can start it up from the android sdk tools folder to view the logs.

Comment: I have this problem of DDMS sometimes generating outputs on Logcat and sometimes it doesn't.  Today it doesn't. Oh yeah, yesterday it did though.

Comment: In the DDMS view you need to select the device you're debugging on to see its log.